# How do I split a string to extract only uppercase string or uppercase followed by float?

Tags: python

I am using Selenium with Python to scrape some file information. I would like to extract only the file type and version number if available eg. `GML 3.1.1`. I'm looking for the split function to do so. My current response is a list that looks like this:

```
ESRI Shapefile, (50.7 kB)
GML 3.1.1, (124.9 kB)
Google Earth KML 2.1, (126.5 kB)
MapInfo MIF, (53.5 kB)
```

The script section is as follows:

```
for file in files:
    file_format = file.text
    print(file_format)
```

I'm looking for the `strip()` function that checks if the word before the comma is uppercase or uppercase followed by float. The following is the output I'm looking for:

```
ESRI
GML 3.1.1
KML 2.1
MIF
```

Comment: split on ',' ?.

Comment: That works but includes "Google Earth", "MapInfo" and "Shapefile" yet what I want is the uppercase letters and version numbers only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a regex that finds words of all uppercase letters followed optionally by a space and digits / dots would work here:

```
s='''ESRI Shapefile, (50.7 kB)
GML 3.1.1, (124.9 kB)
Google Earth KML 2.1, (126.5 kB)
MapInfo MIF, (53.5 kB)'''

import re

re.findall(r'\b[A-Z]+\b(?:\s[\d\.]+)?', s)
['ESRI', 'GML 3.1.1', 'KML 2.1', 'MIF']
```

Comment: Perfect, worked exactly how I wanted it to. Thanks! @Mark

Comment: Shouldn't `(?:\s[\d\.]+)` be captured?

Comment: @thedemons no, I don't think so because that would just give the captured groups resulting in something like `['', ' 3.1.1', ' 2.1', '']`